# Trouble with playing sounds from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wrote myself a script to check a thing periodically. I'd like to make some sound notification for it.

I tried this

```
a = new Audio()
a.src = "file:///usr/share/sounds/LinuxMint/stereo/desktop-logout.ogg"
a.play()
```

but this fails silently.

How should I play a local file from pure JavaScript?

Comment: Why don't you just move the sound file into the dir your script is? If you could access one's file system just like that, I could easily write a snippet here that could fetch ALL your files.

Comment: This doesn't help either. I've explained why